# Does anyone know how to add google maps to an angular 2 app?

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

Does anyone know how to add google maps to an angular 2 app ?

I'm currently linking to it in my index.html page like so:

```
   <script src="node_modules/angular2-google-maps/bundles/angular2-google-maps.js"></script>
```

But I get this console error when using it in my angular 2 component:

system.src.js:1061 GET http://localhost:3000/angular2-google-maps/core 404 (Not Found)

**This is the screen shot of my console:**

[image]

**system config:**

```
System.config({
  packages: {      
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'angular2-google-maps': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  }
});
System.import('app/boot')
      .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Comment: Did you configure systemjs?

Comment: yeh, I've added my current steps below

Answer (score 8):

After a Long reaserch I found the following solution,

Once we installed Angular2-google-maps we forgot to map js file in our config.

Open Your systemjs.config.js

And Add  `'angular2-google-maps/core': 'npm:angular2-google-maps/core/core.umd.js'` in your map directory.

My Code :

```
map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
     'angular2-google-maps/core': 'npm:angular2-google-maps/core/core.umd.js'
    },
```

It may help someone.
Thanks!.

Comment: For my project, I had the following configuration to solve the issue: `angular2-google-maps/core': 'node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core/core.umd.js',`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forgot to add it to your system.js config:

```
  var packages = {
    ...
    'angular2-google-maps':       { defaultExtension: 'js' } <== this line
  };
```

See also http://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html#angular2-google-maps-setup (Section Update systemjs.config.js)

It works only with angular2^rc.X

Comment: I've just added this:     'angular2-google-maps': { defaultExtension: 'js' }

But now I get this console error: "system.src.js:1061 GET http://localhost:3000/@angular/core 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: I import it like this to my index.html :        <script src="node_modules/angular2-google-maps/bundles/angular2-google-maps.js"></script>

Comment: This is how i import it into my boot.ts file: 

import {ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

Comment: I tried it and it works. Can you show us your system.js config?

Comment: added system config above

Comment: What is version angular2 do you use?

Comment: "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",

Comment: You need to update angular2 because package `angular2-google-maps` uses angular2.rc1 https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps/blob/master/package.json#L27

Comment: My package doesnt recognise:  "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113257/discussion-between-yurzui-and-angularm).

Comment: I have made a build folder using your code but its asking for the '@angular' library's. could you help me with this?

Comment: can you take a look at this question I made. Its basically the app we worked on but im struggling with the build package that im deploying to live web to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525356/how-to-create-an-angular-2-build-folder-when-using-systemjs-config-js